# how to call external method of a class with parameters from a jsp page and return the result to it?

Tags: java, jsp

I am doing project in jsp in which i need to call some methods of an external class and the result from that method has to be received by jsp for further processing.The returned result is of image form.

for example,

```
Key=Crypting.KeyGen(width,height);
Encrypt=Crypting.Encrypt(Key,Src);
```

My doubt is, is this correct way of calling an external method?

Comment: Generally yes, this is the correct way to call an external method. Specifically to JSP and Java EE, you should always avoid mixing the UI part with the control part. Use JSPs only to render, and use regular servlets to do the "control" job. You may also want to take a look at [MVC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html) for your next applications.

Comment: What are external methods/classes?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.If I use scriptlets does it make server overload? i.e frequently calling method of the class

Comment: @SKJ If the method generates server overload it will happen, no matter if you call it from JSP, scriptlet or servlet. All of them get executed server-side, so a heavy method call will generate server overload, no matter where you call it from. (JSP itself is a servlet BTW)

Comment: @BackSlash  Sry i thought jsp and servlet are different .BTW thanks for ur help

Comment: @SKJ They are different, you code them differently, but at compile-time JSP gets converted to a regular Servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following Code...

**Sample Code**

In class file method should be `public`

```
  //Here Test class inside com.example packege
    package com.example;

    public class Test {
            public static String displayInfo(){
                return "This is Display Method...";
            }
        }
```

In JSP File you need to import the package respectively class.

```
 // JSP File and here calling Test Class displayInfo() Static method
   <%@page import="com.example.Test"%>
   <html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!!!</h1>
        <%
        out.print("welcome to jsp "+Test.displayInfo());
        %>
    </body>
    </html>
```

hope it will help you...